# Python ValueError but shapes match

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am getting a value error but the shape of my input variables look like they match. Here is the error:

`ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [644170, 14]`

Here is my code:

```
# 10-K Folds
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=1)
results = cross_val_score(estimator = grid.best_estimator_, X = X, y = y, cv = kfold, scoring = 'f1_macro') # https://scikit-learn.org/0.17/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score.html
results # Array of scores of the estimator for each run of the cross validation.
```

Here are the shapes:

```
X.shape
(644170, 14)

y.shape
(14,)
```

There is a 14 in both shapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to be here:

```
X.shape
# (644170, 14)

y.shape
# (14)
```

You have 644170 observations (with 14 features) in the training set and as a target you only have 14 values ​​... you should have 644170 target values ​​to do cross validation.

To clarify the ideas look at this classic example based on the iris dataset that you find on the sklearn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html):

```
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
X = diabetes.data[:150]
y = diabetes.target[:150]
lasso = linear_model.Lasso()
cross_val_score(lasso, X, y, cv=3)
```

and the dimensions of X and y are:

```
X.shape
# (150, 10)

y.shape

# (150,)
```

or a target value for each observation of the training set.

Comment: i am not 100% sure but I think y.shape should be (150,1) and can not be (150,0)

Comment: @VenkataSriHarshaVemuluru Yes of course you're right, It's a vector. My mistake in copying and pasting. Thanks